# workfusion webelement has two variable ad doesnt take anything

Tags: variables, selenium-webdriver, workfusion

Workfusion I am trying to make two variables through web-element. When running individually its great but when running separately it has problems.

Please see the picture for the same. This doesn't get executed.

[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Have you tried specifying XPath there directly? In WF, accessing variable inside another access statement is always tricky - in webharvest, in recorder, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your XPath has any variable then try the giving a value like following:

```
//*[@id="mv-tiles"]/a[${i}]
```

and you can keep changing value of i through loop. A variable inside another will throw error in Workfusion RPA Express.

Answer (score 0):

The ${} evaluates the whole it's body.
Does the following, without nested ${} execute OK?

```
${webrange[countertemp]}
```